# facing Trying to get property 'name' of non-object problem can't solved it

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

When i am want to show my employee profile and want to add department and designation from another table i am facing this problem. I can't solved it..i saw previous question but can't solved my answers.

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $data['title'] = "Profile";
    $data['employee'] = Employee::with(['department','designation'])->findOrFail($id);
    $data['departments'] = Department::orderBy('name')->pluck('name','id');
    $data['designations'] = Designation::orderBy('name')->pluck('name','id');
    return view('admin.employee.show',$data);
}
```

view:

```
<li>
  <div class="title">Department:</div>
  <div class="text">{{ $employee->department->name }}</div>
</li>
```

Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Employee extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Notifiable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname','lastname', 'email', 'password','designation_id','department_id'];

    public function designation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Designation::class);
    }
    public function department()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }
}
```

Department Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Department extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable=['name','depatment_details'];


}
```

Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm\resources\views\admin\employee\show.blade.php)

Comment: Is the department not soft deleted? If so, you can add a WithTrashed relation for the department. And eager load it, then use it like: `{{ $employee->departmentWithTrashed->name }}`. Or you can do something like this if you don't want to show deleted departments: `{{ $employee->department->name ?? 'None' }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
<li>
  <div class="title">Department:</div>
  <div class="text">{{ $data['employee']->department->name }}</div>
</li>
```

Comment: it give me this error "Undefined variable: data (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm\resources\views\admin\employee\show.blade.php)"

Comment: Can we see your department model.

Comment: i give department model in the above code.please check it

Comment: Have you added a foreign department_id key to your eployee table? Try also specifying it in department relation like so  return $this->belongsTo(Department::class. 'department_id');

Comment: yes see "$table->unsignedBigInteger('department_id');
            $table->foreign('department_id')->references('id')->on('departments');"

Comment: This could then just be an issue of some emloyyes not having their departments which then gives you an error after trying to access property name on null. You could use a condition in blade to see whether relation is null before trying to access name.

Comment: can you give a code how to check relation is null or not